# Loss for upgrading marketing cloud connector package

Tags: marketing-cloud

The individual email results have seemed to stopped being sent from marketing cloud to sales cloud instance.

After that our connector broke and we had to reinstall the upgraded connector package.

So i have few question :

1. What is the causing issue ?
2. Do we need to upgrade the package ?
3. How can i get my tracking data because everything is loss
4. What is the best practice ?

Please suggest

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Marketing Cloud package in Salesforce is out of date then there can be some erratic behavior, such as some IER's not being sent, some tracking data not getting updated or IER image's being broken.

However the Marketing Cloud Connector generally doesn't break on it's own, it's likely that one (or several) of the following happened:

- API / tracking User password was changed in Sales Cloud or Marketing Cloud
- API / tracking User tokens were cleared or corrupted in Sales Cloud
- API / tracking User permissions or profile was changed in Sales Cloud
- Request Limit exceeded for API calls
- Sales Cloud storage limit exceeded

Generally you would get a [Deferment Notice](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_deferment_notices.htm&type=5) email if any of those happened though.

Other than that there is no way to trace this down by yourself, so I would advise creating a Marketing Cloud support case and ask them to check their logs.

Marketing Cloud packages should be updated whenever there is a new version released, but fortunately Saleforce is going to be [automating this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_august_2018_auto-upgrade_packages.htm&type=5) from 2019 onwards.

Unfortunately there is no way to retrieve the lost IER's back to Sales Cloud. I've been in your situation before and had several discussions with support about this. The least you can do is create these IER's manually in Sales Cloud.

This means you would need to use your tracking data in Marketing Cloud to create suitable CSV files for Salesforce Data Loader (or any other preferred tool) and just mass-create them like this. Noting that preparing these files is a very tedious and time-consuming process.

Best practice is to set up the Marketing Cloud Connect the proper way and not touch the API user credentials and tokens unless you absolutely need to.

- [Marketing Cloud Connect Troubleshooting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_troubleshooting_guide.htm&type=5)
- [Marketing Cloud Connect Authentication FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_authentication_faqs.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.It's very helpful information .